# Multiple Items in List View are not focused (Color does not change)

Tags: android, listview, focus, selector

This question has been many times and i searched a lot on it but almost all the solutions are not working for me. I want to select multiple items of listview and as i select the color of selected item changes. i.e. if there are 10 items in list view and i select 5 items then the color of these 5 items should be changed and are in focus so that i can perform operation on them. But every solution is not working for me only the current selected item changed but not all items are focused and change.

I tried with many codes and this is one of them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item 
android:state_selected="false"
android:state_pressed="false" 
android:drawable="@drawable/normal_shape" />

<item android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
android:state_pressed="false" 
android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" /> 
</selector>
```

gradient_bg_hover:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
  android:startColor="#d9dd00"
  android:endColor="#e6ea02"
  android:angle="270" />
 </shape>
```

normal_shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#fefeff"
    android:startColor="#d5dbe7" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#acd9dd" />

</shape>
```

and in my listview here is the xml code:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messageList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="@null"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listsele"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

Whats the issue ? why are the items selected by me are not focused and not changing colors

Comment: do u know how to update adapter

Comment: by update you mean?

Comment: change the Array and update the list

Comment: can you provide me sample code for this please?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
 android:cacheColorHint="@null"
```

And use selector as background